# Graphviz: striped horizontally?

Tags: graphviz

In graphviz I can do something like

```
node [style=striped fillcolor="black;0.333:red;0.333:gold;0.333"]
```

to create vertical stripes that are next each other from left to right.

For example that would allow me to create the Belgian flag. Is there a way to stripe in the other direction, that is horizontally or stacked on top each other? So that I could create the German flag, for instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way, using "html-like" node:

```
graph GF{
 GF [shape=plaintext  label=<
    <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
      <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="50" WIDTH="300" BGCOLOR="black">  </TD></TR>
      <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="50" WIDTH="300" BGCOLOR="red">  </TD></TR>
      <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="50" WIDTH="300" BGCOLOR="gold">  </TD></TR>
</TABLE>>]
}
```

Giving:
[image]